# Group by a COUNT subquery in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery

would love suggestions on how to achieve my needs as explained below -

Group by a subquery result, example of such a scenario:
I got a table of `transactionLog`, each transaction can be processed multiple times.
I have a large statistics query to analyze stuff by attempts count, for example -
The total transactions amount grouped by process count.

The query I tried to build in order to achieve the example above was:

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(Amount),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [db].[dbo].[transactionlog] t2 WHERE t2.OrderGuid = [db].[dbo].[transactionlog].OrderGuid) as 'ProccessCount'
  FROM [db].[dbo].[transactionlog]

  group by 'ProccessCount'
```

Which throws:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Obviously my real life scenario is a bit wider, this example is only a way to explain what I'm trying to achieve.
In real life I have multiple queries like so with different where clause for different types of statistics which I union all of them together to one result set. 
seems like the union and everything works fine, it just the group by that doesn't work.

Thanks!

~~EDIT - further explanation of my specific situation ~~
Lets say I don't have a field called OrderGuid.

`TransactionLog` is built as such -

```
TransactionLogId (primary key)
Amount
ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId (default to 0)
```

Every original transaction has the field `ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId` set to 0.
Every time a transaction is reprocessed a new transaction is been inserted with `ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId` set to the `TransactionLog` of the original transaction.

I want to achieve the same thing - to sum the amount of all the transactions grouped by the process attempts count.

Sample Data -

```
TransactionLogId:1, Amount:100, ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId :0
TransactionLogId:2, Amount:100, ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId :0
TransactionLogId:3, Amount:100, ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId :1
```

I want to have a query which will result with -

```
ProcessAttempts : 1, TotalAmount : 100
ProcessAttempts : 2, TotalAmount : 200
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Stop putting identifiers in single quotes which make them string literals.

Comment: lol, I'll stop :)
Thanks for pointing that out. Gordon I won't provide sample data as you already solved my query. thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT ProcessCount, SUM(Amount), COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT SUM(Amount) as Amount, COUNT(*) as ProcessCount
      FROM [db].[dbo].[transactionlog] tl
      GROUP BY IIF(ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId = 0, TransactionLogId, ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId)
     ) og
GROUP BY ProcessCount
ORDER BY ProcessCount;
```

This first aggregates by `OrderGuid` to get the count and sum for each order.  It this aggregates to get the number (and amount) for orders with each number of transactions.

Comment: Hey Gordon, as your answer works its not exactly what I needed (fail on my end with a bad example). I added further explanation and sample data to my post, please re visit :)

Comment: @Ben replacing `OrderGuid` in the above with an expression such as `IIF(ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId = 0, TransactionLogId, ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId)` should do it.

Comment: @SalmanA Not sure what you mean, can you show me an example? Thanks!

Comment: @Ben... just find-replace `tl.OrderGuid` with that expression in the above example.

Answer (score 2):

Silly mistaek but this:

```
group by 'ProccessCount'
```

Should be:

```
group by ProccessCount
```

Right now you're grouping by a ***string*** `'ProcessCount'` which throws that error, but then you cannot group on something that is calculated in select clause. You need to do something like this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SUM(Amount) AS txn_total, COUNT(*) AS attempts
    FROM transactionlog
    GROUP BY ISNULL(NULLIF(ExtraProcessOfTransactionLogId, 0), TransactionLogId)
)
SELECT attempts, SUM(txn_total) AS sum_txn_total
FROM cte
GROUP BY attempts
ORDER BY attempts
```